# How to write get method for class bassed on ListView

Tags: django, django-views

I try to write get method for my class bassed on ListView, I want to get request from form in template and return model with filter from request. This is part of my code:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'projects_list'
    template_name = 'projects/search.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        do smth??
        return self.render_to_response(??)
```

My form:

```
<form class="well form-search" action="/search/" method="get">
    <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" name="q">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

Plz, give me some example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to rewrite `get` method.

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'projects_list'
    template_name = 'projects/search.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return Model.objects.filter(title=q)
```

Comment: `title=q` looks like it should be `title=query`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use super() like this:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        do smth??
        return super(SearchListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```